# Core Data @sum and @count for 3 table relationship (one to many)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship

I have the following schema:

- Table Customer: `Name`
- Table Order: `OrderDate`, `Amount`
- Table OrderDetails: `ItemName`, `Amount`

The one to many relationship goes like `Customer --> Orders --> OrderDetails`
I need to get the query `@sum` and `@count` on the `Orders` and `OrderDetails` tables respectivly.

I tried `valueForKeyPath`, but it only works on the Orders table and cant get to the `OrderDetails` table:

```
[Customer valueForKeyPath:@"orders.@sum.amount"]
```

what I'm looking for to get the count of `Orderdetails`, or get the count using a nested predicate (performance is an issue) e.g:

```
[Customer valueForKeyPath: @"orders.OrderDetails.@count.ItemName]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second one is incorrect as you are mixing attributes and class names and missing a step.  If you want the count of order details for all orders of a customer then you need to do a bit more work.  First lets look at this without rolling everything into one call to make it easier to follow:

```
NSSet *orders = [customer valueForKey:@"orders"];
NSSet *details = [orders valueForKey:@"orderDetails"];
NSInteger count = [details count];
```

So with this it works.  But you want it in one line.  To do that we need to combine all of the order details from the multiple orders before we attempt a count.  The code above does that as a side effect of calling `-valueForKey:` on a `NSSet`.  However we can do it intentionally with KVC:

```
NSSet *details = [customer valueForKeyPath:@"orders.@distinctUnionOfSets.orderDetails"];
NSInteger count = [details count];
```

The `@distinctUnionOfSets` tells KVC to call `-valueForKey:` on the results from `orders` and that it should expect to get back one or more instances of `NSSet` and the combine the contents of those instances into a single `NSSet` and return it.  Now the only thing left is to put count on the end:

```
NSInteger count = [customer valueForKeyPath:@"orders.@distinctUnionOfSets.orderDetails.@count"];
```

In your code you were doing two things incorrectly.  You were referencing the object classname instead of the instance names (I guessed at what they should be) and you were not combining the sets coming back so that the count would work correctly.

More details on KVC can be found on [Apple's Developer Website](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html).

Comment: works but the last combined valueForKeyPath@"orders.@distinctUnionOfSets.orderDetails.@count"]

Comment: works but the last combined 

valueForKeyPath@"orders.@distinctUnionOfSets.orderDetails.@count"]

errors: -[NSMutableSet unionSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet'


if I split the above keypath to an NSSet details then an NSinteger count, it works,

Comment: If it works then you should accept the answer.  Also if the last one is not working for you then it is a good idea to figure out why so that you can learn KVC.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is very illuminating. I too got it to work, except for the same error that @user1194556 got. I've thought about your solution and I'm not sure I understand why, and I would like to. Finally: is it possible to use this in an NSSortDescriptor? (I'm thinking perhaps not, as there is no method to create an NSSortDescriptor with a key *path*).

Comment: Since the `@count` doesn't work (most likely because it tries to apply the count first instead of last), I doubt you would have success with a sort descriptor.  But it is worth a try, who knows, it might surprise you :)